# Title is not aligned with the body in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am trying to make a align the heading(title) contents with the body that is the list item here. But it is not getting aligned. If I align it and reduce my screen size (I am using flutter web) it gives a render flex. If I use an expanded widget to align it it doesn't get itself aligned with the body (if I reduce it to half my screen). If I maximise my screen it s getting aligned

I want it to fit even I reduce the screen size.

How do I do it?

Here is the image:

[image]

Here is my code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'Postsc.dart';
late List<Post> drivers;
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
// to set the root of app.
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage1(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage1 extends StatefulWidget {
  late final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePage1State createState() => _MyHomePage1State();
}

class _MyHomePage1State extends State<MyHomePage1> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Center(
          child: Text("Customer Table",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body:Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                  children: [
                     const Text('Cid',
                          style:TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )
                      ),

                    ( SizedBox(width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.225)),
                    const Text('Cname',
                        style:TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )
                    ),
                    ( SizedBox(width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.20) ),
                    const Text('Cadd',
                        style:TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )
                    ),
                    ( SizedBox(width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.22)),
                    const Text('Ctype',
                        style:TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )
                    ),
                  ]
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child:_buildBody(context),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        color:const Color(0xFF303030),
      ),
      );
  }

  // build list view & manage states
  FutureBuilder<List<Post>> _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    final HttpService httpService = HttpService();
    return FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
      future: httpService.getPosts(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          final List<Post>? posts = snapshot.data; //marked
          return _buildPosts(context, posts!);
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
  // build list view & its tile
  ListView _buildPosts(BuildContext context, List<Post> posts) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          height:70,
          child: Card(
            shadowColor: Colors.white,
            color:const Color(0xFF303030),
            elevation: 1,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(posts[index].Cid,style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color:Colors.white,),),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(posts[index].Cname,style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color:Colors.white,),),
                  ),),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(posts[index].Cadd,style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color:Colors.white,),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(posts[index].Ctype,style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color:Colors.white,),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
class HttpService {
  Future<List<Post>> getPosts() async {
    Response res = await get(
        Uri.parse('http://localhost/localconnect/customer_change.php'));
    print(res.body);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(res.body);
      List<Post> posts = body.map(
            (dynamic item) => Post.fromJson(item),
      ).toList();
      return posts;
    } else {
      throw "Unable to retrieve posts.";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Expanded` instead of using `SizedBox` and `MediaQuery`:.

Like so:

```
Row(
    children: [
      const Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'Cid',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'Cname',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'Cadd',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'Ctype',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try **Expanded** widget except using of **SizedBox**

here is some code:

```html
class MyHomePage1 extends StatefulWidget {
  late final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePage1State createState() => _MyHomePage1State();
}

class _MyHomePage1State extends State<MyHomePage1> {
  List l = [
    {"number": "1", "name": "warner", "place": 'sydney', "des": 'Regular customer'},
    {"number": "1", "name": "warner", "place": 'sydney', "des": 'Regular customer'},
    {"number": "1", "name": "warner", "place": 'sydney', "des": 'Regular customer'},
    {"number": "1", "name": "warner", "place": 'sydney', "des": 'Regular customer'},
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Center(
          child: Text(
            "Customer Table",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: const [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text('Cid',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text('Cname',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text('Cadd',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text('Ctype',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: l
                    .map(
                      (e) => Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              e['number'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              e['name'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              e['place'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              e['des'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        color: const Color(0xFF303030),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]